# How to fetch selected items from ArrayCollection based on start Index and end Index?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I want to retrieve selected items from ArrayCollection by using start index and end index, is there any predefined method to do this...
               Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at toArray and slice.

```
var newAC:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( myAC.toArray().slice(10,20) );
//myAc = original ArrayCollection, 10 = startIndex, 20 = endIndex
```